# Shutting down a Mojo::IOLoop recurring event connected to a Mojo websocket

Tags: perl, websocket, mojolicious, mojo, ioloop

I'm playing around with Mojolicious and websockets. I want to send the output of multiple external commands on the server to the webpage. I have no problems with connecting and receiving messages, but I also want to send a message back to the server to stop an external command while letting the others keep sending messages back to the client. I also want to stop checking the external command once it exits.

The external command is simply a one-liner that spits out an integer every few seconds. I have two websockets that display the numbers in separate `div`s. Clicking either of the stop buttons sends the message, but that's where I need to figure out how to shut down that websocket (and only that websocket) and shut down the external command.

[image]

When I connect the websocket, I run the external command and set up a `Mojo::IOLoop->recurring` to check if there's output.

When I want to stop, I figure that I should call `Mojo::IOLoop->remove($id)`, but that doesn't seem to completely remove it and I get error messages like `Mojo::Reactor::Poll: Timer failed: Can't call method "is_websocket" on an undefined value`.

If I call `finish` on the controller object to shut down the websocket, it seems to stop everything.

I have the entire [Mojolicious::Lite app as a gist](https://gist.github.com/briandfoy/75e8c06669beca69b3078269438cbed9), but here's the parts where I

```
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);
## other boilerplate redacted

websocket '/find' => sub ( $c ) {
    state $loop = Mojo::IOLoop->singleton;

    app->log->debug( "websocket for find" );
    $c->inactivity_timeout( 50 );

    my $id;
    $c->on( message => sub ( $ws, $message ) {
        my $json = decode_json( $message );
        my $command = $json->{c};
        my $name    = $json->{n};

        app->log->debug( "Got $command command for $name" );
        if( $command eq "start" ) {
            $id = run_command( $ws );
            app->log->debug( "run_command for $name returned [$id]" );
            }
        elsif( $command eq "stop" ) {
            app->log->debug( "stopping loop for $name [$id]" );
            # XXX What should I do here?
            # $ws->finish;
            # $loop->remove( $id );
            }
        elsif( $command eq "open" ) {
            app->log->debug( "opening websocket for $name" );
            }
        }
        );
     $c->on(
        finish => sub ( $c, $code ) {
            app->log->debug("WebSocket closed with status $code");
            }
        );
    };

app->start;

sub run_command ( $ws ) {
    app->log->debug( "In run_command: $ws" );
    open my $fh, "$^X -le '\$|++; while(1) { print int rand(100); sleep 3 }' |";
    $fh->autoflush;

    my $id;
    $id = Mojo::IOLoop->recurring( 1 => sub ($loop) {
        my $m = <$fh>;
        unless( defined $m ) {
            app->log->debug( "Closing down recurring loop from the inside [$id]" );
            # XXX: what should I do here?
            close $fh;
            return;
            };
        chomp $m;
        app->log->debug( "Input [$m] for [$id] from $fh" );
        $ws->send( encode_json( { 'm' => $m } ) );
        });

    return $id;
    }
```

---

Other questions that may benefit from this answer:

- [Output command to socket without buffering using Mojo::IOLoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171833/output-command-to-socket-without-buffering-using-mojoioloop?rq=1)

Comment: Does Mojolicious enable Perl6-style sub argument declaration?

Comment: Perl v5.20 has subroutine signatures as an experimental feature:http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with this a bit. [Logioniz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692340/2766176) made me think that I shouldn't be polling or handling the filehandle details myself. I still don't know where it was hanging.

Instead, I used [Mojo::Reactor](http://www.metacpan.org/module/)'s `io` to set a filehandle to monitor:

```
sub run_command ( $ws ) {
    my $pid = open my $fh, "$^X -le '\$|++; print \$\$; while(1) { print int rand(100); sleep 3 }' |";
    $fh->autoflush;

    my $reactor = Mojo::IOLoop->singleton->reactor->io(
        $fh => sub ($reactor, $writeable) {
            my $m = <$fh>;
            chomp $m;
            $ws->send( encode_json( { 'm' => $m } ) );
            }
        );

    return ( $fh, $pid );
    }
```

When I'm done with that command, I can unwatch that filehandle and kill the process. I finish the websocket:

```
    elsif( $command eq "stop" ) {
        $loop->reactor->watch( $fh, 0, 0 );
        kill 'KILL', $pid or app->log->debug( "Could not kill $pid: $!" );
        $ws->finish;
        }
```

I still don't know why `remove($fh)` doesn't work. I figure I'm leaking some IOLoop things doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you block event loop because your recurrent invoke every second and `my $m = <$fh>;` wait result about 2-3 second. So you block event loop.
I think so because when i run your app the event `finish` not call on inactivity timeout, but call event `recurrent`. `finish` event MUST call on inactivity timeout always.

I think that your code must be in separate process to avoid blocking event loop.

Try to use [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop::ReadWriteFork) module to execute in separate process.
I [write](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/0c08e4974ab20b190382a429b913d8e6) small example.